# Flash AS3 Loading XML from server (from Flash Pro AND Flash Builder)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, svn, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I am making a project that uses an external xml file. I am publishing from Flash Professional and I can just put the xml in the bin folder, and when saying the path use this:

```
_xmlPath = "blit_test_4.xml";
_xmlRequest = new URLRequest(_xmlPath);
```

It works great!

However, I then tried to make an actionscript mobile project in flash builder and compile from there. No matter where I put the xml file, even in the bin-debug folder, it doesn't read the file and gives me an error. I do have an svn repository set up by cloud forge, but for some reason I cannot connect at all to this. I tried this line in code:

```
_xmlPath = "https://goldenliongames.svn.cloudforge.com/rufood/HeadExploder/bin-debug/blit_test_4.xml"
```

Can someone help me out here? Also, I would like to have a flexible system so I can use these xml files in a app that is published to the stores. Thanks!

Comment: I know someone out there has used external xml files in as3 projects. Please help me or just give me a quick tip to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you connect to `https://goldenliongames.svn.cloudforge.com/rufood/HeadExploder/` ? If so, then maybe your `bin-debug` folder hasn't been `svn add`ed and `svn commit`ted to the repo. Also, check that the folder hasn't been added to `HeadExploder`s `svn:ignore` list

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, I was talking to people from beanstalk and it seems that I was just doing it wrong. I was trying to use the repository for version control and hosting the assets when really subversion repositories should only be used for backing up your files and versioning. I went with Amazon S3 which is basically exactly what I was looking for, a spot "in the internet" where I could drop my swf, xml, image, sound files and have a path generated for my games to reference. It ended up looking something like this:

```
_xmlPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xmlFiles/1234235/explosion_guy.xml";
```